# Subquery which returns several columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have 2 tables as follows:

[image]

[image]

I have to display a list of manager names and his/her maximum project budget. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT emp.Name, proj.Budget
FROM EmployeeStatistics emp, Projects proj
WHERE (emp.EmployeeID, proj.Budget) IN (SELECT EmployeeIDNO, MAX(Budget)                                                                          
                                        FROM Projects                                                                             
                                        GROUP BY EmployeeIDNO)
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

[image]

Now, if I run the sub-query only, the result is:

[image]

In my main query I just need to associate the names and budget to the result of the sub-query but this is what I am not being able to figure out

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Skip IN, JOIN the subquery instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `JOIN` should work, no subquery needed.  This is the [explicit join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins):

```
SELECT emp.Name, MAX(proj.Budget) as MaxBudget
FROM EmployeeStatistics emp
JOIN Projects proj on emp.EmployeeID = proj.EmployeeIDNO
GROUP BY emp.Name
```

If you want to include employees that have no budget, use `LEFT JOIN` instead.